# Higher RAM vs Higher Storage

Tags: video, memory, storage, imovie

I am planning to buy the new MacbookAir with M1 chip.

My usage

1. Basic Word, PowerPoint editing. Plan to use native Pages and Keynotes.
2. Frequent video editing using iMovie and Kdenlive. I do not require 4K. 720p at 30fps is fine.
3. Latex editor
4. VPN and ssh to remotely login to a ubuntu server.
5. Google docs and google spreadsheets (online)

The base model comes with 8GB RAM with 256GB storage. If I wish to spend extra money which of the following should I go for:

- 16 GB RAM with 256 GB storage
- 8GB RAM with 512 GB storage
- Go for MACbook pro with 8GB RAM and 256 GB storage.
- or the basic MACbook Air should be fine?

I personally think to go either for second or last option.

I do not intend to do any gaming or storing lots of images, movies, audios, etc. Mostly all my docs and PPTS will also be saved on drive and not locally. Immediately after rendering videos in .mp4 format they will be uploaded to Youtube and do not require save them MacBook Air storage.

Comment: RAM and memory are different words for the same thing

Comment: What do you think you need extra storage for?

Comment: You can expand storage with external storage.  RAM not

Comment: Shopping questions are off topic,  it in the end, doesn’t this involve your personal budget? How much is your time worth and can you measure any difference in your valuable time by upgrading past the basic Mac? In fact, compared to what you have today, it might be a wash so buy what you can afford and resell it once you know what you need would be the general advice. Would this help you edit this so it’s not opinion based. No one can know what you need since there are no facts here to analyze, just opinions and guesses.

Comment: Get the base air.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opinion-based this may be… however, there's a slightly new paradigm with the M1 "Hard disk" storage configuration.

It is so fast that it makes additional RAM less useful than it was in the past. This is because it is now part of the same chip, rather than having to be accessed over a bus system to another component.

Received wisdom if you have to choose between the two is to go for more "SSD" storage rather than more RAM, as paging is now almost instantaneous.

Another consideration is that once chosen, it can never be changed, so don't come up short on storage, unless you want to be carrying round an external drive for the next few years.

Having said that, no-one can choose for you, you have to finally make your own call ;)

I shall be using this same received wisdom in a week's time, when the Apple Store opens orders for me to buy a new iMac. Right now, I'm going to be going for 512GB or 1TB "SSD" & possibly only 8GB RAM, depending on pricing [which I cannot see just yet].

Comment: RE: "I shall be using this same received wisdom in 45 minutes' time, when the Apple Store opens orders for me to buy a new iMac." --  From [Buy the all-new 24” iMac](https://www.apple.com/shop/buy-mac/imac) it states "Order 4.30. Available second half of May.", so how are you going to order it today?

Comment: "Order 4:30… it's now 3:56...

Comment: Do you have resources I can read about the paging speed up? That's very interesting

Comment: Oh FFS, stupid american dates. I was on the US Store. How is any rational human being supposed to read 4.30 as a **date** Darnit, I've been waiting all day for it to open… stoopid stoopid backwards dates system & poor redirect structure, the UK shop should be apple.co.uk,. not apple.com/uk … grrrr…. </rant> Anyway, I fixed my anticipatory wait in the answer ;))

Comment: @theonlygusti - it's inherent in the architecture. I don't have a distinct ref with figures.

Comment: RE: "Oh FFS, stupid american dates. " --  If you are going to disparage Americans, please have a look at: [British Movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pPY-sCiRCeA)

Comment: @user3439894 - I may have been joking, btw; it's  british thing ;)) That S&S showreel is an idea that could have been more convincing. btw, I'm not disparaging Americans, just the incomprehensible date system. Rest of the world does it the other way round. I could go on about how you drive on the wrong side of the road too, but only common sense is on my side there rather than percentage of countries [& everybody drives an automatic, so there's no 'steer with your good hand, change gear with the other' influence.] Basically, I'm blaming the US for making me wait a week rather than an hour :P

Comment: Tetsujin, First of all I hope you know that my retort was in jest. That said though, to criticize how we do something is not really any different than disparaging us. Having lived in England, I have to say there are many things I miss about it. It's a beautiful country, as is the USA!

Comment: "to criticize how we do something is not really any different than disparaging us" Yes it is, it's completely & utterly different. You can't read tone of voice in text, so try not to extract the maximum amount of offence from anything you may read. Try not to infer that which may not have been implied.